# Find the domain and range of the function $f(x) = |x-1|$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I found the domain of $f$ which comes out to be $R$ (the set of all real numbers)

But how do I find the range of the function?

Comment: It has to be contained in $[0,\infty)$ (Why?). Can you see why it is the whole of $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: I do know the answer, because modulus always gives a positive value (for positive and negative numbers) and zero (for zero). What I need are the steps to arriving at this conclusion...

Comment: So, do you just mention that a modulus function always gives non-negative outputs and that's it?

Comment: A modulus function always gives non-negative outputs. That is clear from the definition of the modulus function.

Comment: Thank You, turns out this was a silly question :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see for which $y$'s does the equation $\lvert x-1\rvert=y$ has a solution. Clearly, it has no solution if $y<0$. If $y=0$, it has one solution: $x=1$. Otherwise, it has two of them: $y+1$ and $-y+1$.

Therefore, the range is $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank You......

Answer (score 2):

By definition of the absolute value,

$$|x-1|\ge0.$$
At this stage, we can say that $\text{range}(f)\subseteq\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, but not more.

Now, the equation $$y=|x-1|$$ has at least one solution for every $y\ge0$, such as $x=y+1$ (it is true that $y=|y+1-1|$, and $y+1$ is always defined). Hence the range is indeed

$$\mathbb R_{\ge0}.$$

Comment: Can we simply just state that $|x-1| \geq 0$ and thus, $f(x) \geq 0$. This means that : $Range(f) = [0,∞)$?

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu: no. Following that logics, $|x-1|\ge-27$ would imply $\text{range}(f)=[-27,\infty)$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

We know as a general rule that substracting any number $k$ to the input of a function results in a right horizontal shift of $k$ units.

So in particular, substacting $1$ in the input of the function $f(x)= |x|$ results in a right horizontal shift of this function ( of its graph, more rigorously) of $1$ unit.

Then $g(x)= f(x-1)= |x-1|$ is , so to say, the absolute value function  shifted $1$ unit to the right.

Function $g$ takes as input any value of $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $(x-1)$ is a possible input of function $f$, that is, such that $(x-1)$ belongs to $\mathbb R$; for function $f(x)=|x|$ is defined on $\mathbb R$. But, $(x-1)$ belongs to $\mathbb R$ for any $x$ value. So the domain is $\mathbb R$.

Since the shift is only horizontal , not vertical, there is no change in the range: the domain of function $g$ is the same as the domain of $f$, namely the positive part of the Y-axis ( point $(0,0)$ included), or $\mathbb R_{+}$.

Answer (score 0):

The domain is undefined, since the symbol $|\cdot|$ applies to several objects. It is only the set of real numbers if $x$ is assumed to be real. Otherwise $x$ could be some infinite-dimesnional vector, for example.

If you set $y=|x-1|,$ then you see that $y$ has to be nonnegative. In other words, the range is contained in the set of all nonnegative real numbers. Finally,  note that $y$ can become arbitrarily large, and also vanishes (when $x=1$), so that the range is indeed the set of all nonnegative reals, since the function is continuous.